# Getting an error that I don't recognise when creating a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I've created a custom `UITableViewCell` in my project and I've made it using a .xib file here is a couple of images of the set up:

[image: Background, selected, and main Cell view]

[image]

This is an image of my main cell, selected, and background for said cell.
This is the link up for the Main Cell.

So as far I am aware this part works fine.

this is the error I'm getting:
[image: Error message]

I thought it was because I was trying to load the cell before the tableview? but my table view loads when the rootViewController does so that can't be it... here is my code for the table view (relevant code):

Key:
`GroupCell` = name of my .h, .m, .xib file of my cell.

`objectivenameArray` = array with the server data collected with an NSString executed with an NSMutableArray.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
    return [objectivenameArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";

    GroupCell *groupCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (groupCell == nil) {
        groupCell = [[GroupCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

        groupCell.objectiveLabel.text = [objectivenameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return groupCell;
}
```

I'll add that I'm using the server API AFNetworking but this should be creating an issue as all my URLData is linked up properly. The problem began to occur when I tried to Load the Custom Cell. Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question; The error I received was because I still had the Auto layout feature switched on my custom cell .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message is pretty clear.

> GroupCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

I assume you have overridden layoutSubviews in GroupCell and you forgot to put [super layoutSubviews] at the beginning of the method. Put that in and the error should go away.

Comment: I thought that was something that wasn't required in the new xcode... Well I tried that but it didn't work :/. I put it in the Cell's .m file inside `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{`

Comment: Ahh copy and pasted the wrong method! I meant `-(void)layoutSubviews {}` but I've not created these programatically. I shouldn't have to code these in this method if they are done in interface builder surely?

Comment: Infuriating. It's because I hadn't switched auto Layout off. Fixed! Thanks for your answer implementing `-(void)layoutSubviews{}` will have helped! cheers!

Comment: So you weren't overriding -layoutSubviews to begin with?

Comment: Apparently not no. Sorry, that's completely my fault for not checking in the cells file inspector. Not used to doing it still since ios6.

Comment: Huh. The error message only mentions layoutSubviews, which is why I went that way. Sounds like it might be a bug in Auto Layout. One more reason to wait on Auto Layout until the bugs are ironed out a bit more.

Comment: Yeh I can understand that - well it was only because I had created the Cell in interface builder and obviously with xcode 4.5 all UIViews and such have Auto layout switched on as standard so it's messed with the code that I had used. Yeh what you said makes sense, Just have to remember to flick it off for certain things! Cheers for you help either way though man.